# SAML Single Sign On Cannot Keep Session Cookie Jmeter

Tags: cookies, jmeter, single-sign-on, session-cookies, saml

I successfully recorded a site that uses SAML Authentication Request and Single Sign On to Login. This site is using a proxy. So, I recorded it using a proxy.

When I played back the record, it successfully login but when I played back for the second times (I run after waiting for 5 seconds), it failed to login. If I checked, the difference is in the Cookie, however I already used HTTP Cookie Manager:

[image]

`successfully login`

[image]

`failed login`

[image]

If we can see the pictures above that the difference is the cookie.

So how to keep the session cookie?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter automatically checks cookies integrity, as per [HTTP Cookie Manager documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager):

> JMeter checks that received cookies are valid for the URL. This means that cross-domain cookies are not stored. If you have bugged behaviour or want Cross-Domain cookies to be used, define the JMeter property `"CookieManager.check.cookies=false".`

There are 2 ways of "defining" the aforementioned property:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=false
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up
2. [Override the property](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) via [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

   ```
   jmeter -JCookieManager.check.cookies=false -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)